# Is it correct to say "I peeped around the door frame at her"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

I put my head around the door frame to secretly look at a woman.

Is it correct to say "**I peeped around the door frame at her**"?

or "**I looked around the door frame to peep at her**"?

Comment: The first one is idiomatic. Peeping is a way of looking, so you don't need both verbs in the sentence.

Comment: Usually the 'frame' is omitted. "I peeped around/through the door at her".